# About an rational aproximation to an irrational

Tags: number-theory, continued-fractions

How to show that if $x$ is an irrational number, then $x= a_{0} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{k_{n}k_{n+1}}$ where the $k_{n}$ are the denominators of the $n$th convergents to $x$?

Maybe a trick is to use the inequalities of the distance between the $n$th and the $n-1$th convergent?

Comment: There's a simple formula for $$\frac{h_n}{k_n} - \frac{h_{n+1}}{k_{n+1}}$$ which yields the sum pretty directly.

Comment: Oh, yeah, the trick is to put in x as a telescopic sum, and the use that formula, thnaks.